# Delete from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete a series of rows from a database using a delete button, but data is split across two tables, joined by one common field. I have created the following, but the delete isn't working right.

```
$watchlist_id = $_GET['id'];

    // Delete Watchlist
    if ($submit == 'Delete Watchlist') {
        require_once("db_connect.php");

        $deleteWatchlist_bad_message = '';

        if ($db_server) {
            $purge_watchlist_query = "DELETE FROM watchlist_films WHERE watchlist_id = '$watchlist_id'";
            mysql_query($purge_watchlist_query) or die("Delete failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $purge_watchlist_query);
            $delete_watchlist_query = "DELETE FROM watchlists WHERE watchlist_id = '$watchlist_id'";
            mysql_query($delete_watchlist_query) or die("Delete failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $delete_watchlist_query);
        } else {
            $deleteWatchlist_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Error: could not connect to the database.</div>';
        }

        require_once("db_close.php");?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "profile.php"
        </script><?php
    }
```

Basically, I want it to delete all the films in the Watchlist in the watchlist_films table (`$purge_watchlist_query`), then delete the Watchlist itself from the watchlists tables (`$delete_watchlist_query`), before redirecting the user back to their profile page.

Apologies for not being clear enough - when I say 'the delete isn't working right', what's actually happening when clicking the delete button is that I am being successfully redirected back to profile.php, however the Watchlist I was attempting to delete is still showing and, when I click through to it, the film it contains is also still there. I aren't getting any errors or anything being spat back out to me, it's just not deleting the records. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: couldnt you do this using database relations ?

Comment: Possibly? I'm a bit of PHP newbie, hence the question. I'm still getting my head around database functions. I have created a successful delete query which completely deletes a user's profile, which works fine, but trying to amend that query doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: What does "isn't working right" mean? Is it deleting anything? Nothing? What exactly is the problem you'd like us to help you solve? If you don't describe the problem, it's very difficult to help you. We can't see your screen or read your mind. Please [edit] and explain the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, the records just don't delete. On clicking the delete button, I'm redirected back to profile.php, but the Watchlist is still there and, clicking back into it, so is the film it contains.

Comment: Are you sure it is going through that part of the code? Are you sure the ID has a number? If any of those two things don't happen, then that code just won't do anything

Comment: @Alex, echoing out $watchlist_id gives me the correct ID of the Watchlist, so it definitely knows which records to find - the ID is correct, it just seems not to be deleting any records which are associated with the ID, in either table.

Comment: @KenWhite Apologies for my vagueness, I have added further clarification to the original post!

Comment: What happens if you echo the queries before running them?

Comment: @Alex Apparently it's not passing in the Watchlist ID after opening the connection to the server, I've echo'd out $watchlist_id before 'if ($submit == 'Delete Watchlist') {' and it finds it correctly, but echoing out $purge_watchlist_query before running it shows 'DELETE FROM watchlist_films WHERE watchlist_id = '

Comment: Ok, maybe you can check whether db_connect.php is doing something with that variable, but the problem was definitely that, then

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26818/discussion-between-alex-and-alex-ryans)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've figured out the problem.

Basically, my original  element was submitting to `watchlist.php`, rather than `watchlist.php?id=$watchlist_id`. Once I'd amended that, the delete worked fine.